# Семантическое сравнение

Tags: семантика

**Оригинал:** *Хватило несколько уроков игры, для того, чтобы он мог играть не хуже профессионала.*

**Русский перевод:** *Хватило несколько уроков игры, после чего он мог играть не хуже профессионала.*

На Ваш взгляд поменялся смысл, если переводчик перевёл целевое предложение временным?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

**1) Русский перевод**: Хватило нескольких уроков игры, **после чего** он мог играть не хуже профессионала.

Это придаточное **присоединительное** предложение, такие предложения  присоединяются к главной части (1) с помощью местоимения ЧТО в различных падежах и с разными предлогами или (2) с помощью местоименных наречий ОТЧЕГО, ПОЧЕМУ и др.. (Пример: Друг нарушил обещание, из-за чего мы с ним поссорились. Комната темная, отчего цветы зачахли).

В нашем случае мы имеем **распространительно-обстоятельственный тип присоединительного предложения**, который удобен для описания **временных**  и причинно-следственных процессов: прошло несколько уроков, и он мог играть не хуже профессионала.

**2) Оригинал:** Хватило нескольких уроков игры, для того чтобы он мог играть не хуже профессионала.

Здесь используется целевой предлог ЧТОБЫ, но само предложение относится к **несобственно-целевому типу** (в этом случае значение цели модифицируется и даже утрачивается). Такие предложения строятся по следующей схеме: **необходимое основание - следствие**, например: Понадобились месяцы, чтобы он мог восстановиться после аварии.

**3) Вывод**

Таким образом, смысл не меняется, но придаточное присоединительное со значением времени яснее передает семантику отношений между главным и придаточным предложениями, **исключая собственно-целевое понимание сложного предложения**.

Answer (score 1):

Запятую надо ставить один раз: Хватило несколько уроков игры, для того чтобы он мог играть не хуже профессионала. или Хватило несколько уроков игры для того, чтобы он мог играть не хуже профессионала.

Answer (score 0):

Насчет смысла - не знаю, от контекста сильно зависит, хотя, похоже, если и поменялся, то не сильно. Насколько вообще важно по контексту акцентировать на причинно-следственную связь вместо связи последовательно-временной?

Второе звучит немного лучше, но главная стилистическая ошибка есть в обоих случаях. Корректно: *Хватило **нескольких** уроков игры...*

А что это за перевод с русского на русский?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я не носитель языка. Оригинал на итальянском.
мне надо проанализировать придаточные предложения и способы их перевода на русский (и объяснить, почему переводчик решился выбрать отличный от оригинала тип придаточного)

Comment: Так давайте итальянский оригинал.  Разберемся.